# Fatal error line 0, Magento module after installation

Tags: php, magento, exception, soap, client

for a client of mine I've installed a new module. After refreshing and logging in again, the backend config page of the module throws this error..

```
Fatal error: Exceptions must be valid objects derived from the Exception base class in /home/<companyname>/public_html/app/code/community/<companyname>/<modulename>/Model/Connector/Soap/Client.php on line 0
```

**Note:** I've placed `<companyname>` and `<modulename>` to respect the companies privacy, and in the cause of anonymity.

The module worked fine on my testing environment, I found out that the PHP version and IonCubeLoader version differ, but not by much.

But is this a server-side problem? Or is there something wrong with my files? Line 0 doesn't even exit?

Hopefully someone can give me some clarity on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the source of that module publicly available? I'd start by checking what exceptions can Client.php produce. It might be that the exception itself was still buggy in your testing env but never got thrown.

Comment: That's also a really good thing to look into. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! I didn't have anything to do with a server-sided version or soap client version. The data in de client.php was IonCubed (encrypted).

So I copied the original (un-encrypted) source and replaced it with the content of the file. It gave an error about line 109, there was a var throwexception specified. I removed it and everything worked again!

Then I've put the throwexception back and the IonCubed content so It's like the original. And refreshed all caches (even varnish) and everything still worked!

Conclusion: Some IonCubed Loader bug

Comment: Unlikely to be Loader bug, and good news that you fixed it! You can always contact http://ioncu.be/S for support assistance if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think  the version of SOAP installed on your server and testing environment is different.

Comment: Thanks, so it was a server-side problem! I called the hosting company, and explained the situation. The PHP, IonCube and SOAP did indeed differ. They've updated it and now it's fixed!